# assignment to expression with array type ch= ch+(s[i]);

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, do-while, c-strings

i am not able to to store character of the character pointer array s into character array ch:

```
    int main() {
    char *s;
    s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);
    char ch[50];
    int i;
    s=s+' ';
    for(i=0;i<=strlen(s)+1;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]!=' ')
        {
            ch= ch+(s[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c \n",ch);
            ch=' ';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the error message:

```
 error: assignment to expression with array type
             ch= ch+(s[i]);
               ^
Solution.c:27:15: error: assignment to expression with array type
             ch=' ';
```

Comment: `ch` is an array type. It can't be used as the left operand of assignment operator.

Comment: ... nor does the whole array correspond correctly to the `%c` printf directive.  Did you perhaps mean `ch[i]` (pretty much everywhere within the loop body)?

Comment: ... and `i<=strlen(s)+1` is one byte off

Comment: BTW there is no real string type in C where you can do things like `mystring = yourstring + " Hello"` etc. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Comment: What is `s=s+' '`?  That's not going to work.  (It'll make `s` point 32 locations beyond where it used to.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of mistakes in your code (some pointed out in the comments). Here's a working fix, that does what I ***think*** you're looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char* s;
    s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 2); // Add 2 because you later append a space!
    //Write your logic to print the tokens of the sentence here.
    //i
    char ch[50] = { '\0' }; // Make sure you initialise the buffer!
    int i;
//  s = s + ' '; // This doesn't do what you think - it's adding the value of ' ' to the string's address!
    strcat(s, " "); // This appends a blank to the string!
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) // For 7 chars, will do [0] thru [6]!
    {
        if (s[i] != ' ')
        {
        //  ch = ch + (s[i]); // You can't just 'add; an element to an array!
            ch[i] = s[i];
        }
        else
        {
        //  printf("%c \n", ch);
            printf("%s \n", ch); // Use this to print the entire ch string so far!
            ch[i] = ' ';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've put comments where I've changed your code; feel free to ask for further explanations!

Comment: thank you! i still have a doubt why do we need to add two more space ? one is for space i understand but what is the other for?

Comment: The `strlen` function returns the length of the string, in character, but ***does not include*** the terminating `nul` character. So, for a string, "abcde", `strlen` will return a value of 5 … but we will need an array of **6** chars to store it: 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', and 'nul'. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

For starters this loop

```
for(i=0;i<=strlen(s)+1;i++)
```

invokes undefined behavior  when i is equal to `strlen(s)+1` because there is an attempt to access memory beyond the dynamically allocated array.

These statements

```
ch= ch+(s[i]);
```

and

```
ch=' ';
```

do not make sense. Arrays do not have the operator `+` and they are non-modifiable lvalues.

A for-loop is not appropriate for such a task because within the loop the last word will not be outputted.

What you mean is the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *s;
    s = malloc(1024 * sizeof( char ) );

    scanf("%1023[^\n]", s);
    s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);


    char ch[50] = { '\0' };

    size_t i = 0, j = 0;

    do
    {
        if ( s[i] != ' ' && s[i] != '\t' && s[i] != '\0' )
        {
            ch[j++] = s[i];
        }
        else if ( ch[0] != '\0' )
        {
            ch[j] = '\0';
            puts( ch );
            j = 0;
            ch[j] = '\0';
        }
    } while ( s[i++] != '\0' );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
Hello muskan litw
```

then the program output will be

```
Hello
muskan
litw
```

Comment: A better answer than mine! Your assumption on what the desired output should be is also probably correct. You get my UV!